# Using dynamic string in C++

Tags: c++, string, function

I have the following code:

```
string *myf()   {
    string *a = new string;
    a="abc";
    return a;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> error: cannot convert 'const char [4]' to 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' in assignment|

Why?

Answer (score 6):

You need a reference to a string to assign into, rather than a pointer:

```
*a = "abc";
```

Or:

```
a->assign("abc");
```

By the way: strings contain pointers to their data internally, so you'd be better off keeping it simple:

```
string myf() {
    return "abc";
}
```

This is more efficient and safer.